What is the fastest way to process nested object array in LWC JS
In my LWC, I am retrieving 1000~ records from wire and have to display the records in a nested object array structure.
I used the array.find method to locate the parent of every record and then initiate the array (if array does not already exist as a property in the object) and push elements to the array.
However even with find method, the JS is taking lot of time to process ~1000 records and create a nested array. I thought manually looping the array using map or for loop would consume lot of time, instead using find would be faster. However even with find, it is still taking ~20 secs to build this array and render in html.
Any thoughts on what would be fastest way to loop/find a record in an nested object array and push new rows to it..
Below is my sample JSON structure: (it does not include all scenarios of nested arrays in below JSON)
[
    {
        "Name": "Oil Gas Salt Resources Act 1990",
        "Id": "a1S05000006zjBuEAI",
        "Question": "a1b05000005E1WJAA0",
        "Type": "Title",
        "Sections": [
            {
                "Display": true,
                "NotRequired": false,
                "Answer": "Not Answered Yet",
                "Name": "4(1) Obstruction of inspector",
                "Question": "a1b05000005E1WKAA0",
                "ParentQuestion": "a1b05000005E1WJAA0",
                "Type": "Section",
                "Id": "a1S05000006zjBvEAI",
                "optionArray": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Compliant",
                        "Value": false,
                        "Display": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Non-Compliant",
                        "Value": false,
                        "Display": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Not Applicable",
                        "Value": false,
                        "Display": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Not Checked",
                        "Value": false,
                        "Display": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Not Answered Yet",
                        "Value": false,
                        "Display": false
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Not Required",
                        "Value": false,
                        "Display": false
                    }
                ],
                "Questions": [
                    {
                        "Answer": "Non-Compliant",
                        "Reason": "test 41 non compliant",
                        "DisplayReason": true,
                        "Display": true,
                        "Name": "4 (1) No person shall hinder, obstruct, molest or interfere with or attempt to hinder, obstruct, molest or interfere with an inspector in the exercise of a power or the performance of a duty under this Act and the regulations. R.S.O. 1990, c. P.12, s. 4 (1).",
                        "Question": "a1b05000005E1WLAA0",
                        "ParentQuestion": "a1b05000005E1WKAA0",
                        "Type": "Question",
                        "Id": "a1S05000006zjBwEAI",
                        "SectionId": "a1b05000005E1WKAA0",
                        "Options": [
                            {
                                "Name": "Compliant",
                                "Value": false,
                                "Display": true
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Non-Compliant",
                                "Value": true,
                                "Display": true
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Not Applicable",
                                "Value": false,
                                "Display": true
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Not Checked",
                                "Value": false,
                                "Display": true
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Not Answered Yet",
                                "Value": false,
                                "Display": false
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Not Required",
                                "Value": false,
                                "Display": false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]


Including any code you've written already would be helpful. It's unclear how you intend to render this in HTML, or what it looks like. I'd suggest, at minimum, the JavaScript, the related HTML template(s), and a screenshot of what it eventually looks like.

Apologies for the delayed response. I fixed this issue. In the wire method, after getting the results from apex, I was looping through the array which I am updating, and I have used @track for this array which I am forming. So i am using temparray to process the complete results from apex, once the complete array is formed, then I am assigning to my array which is iterated in html.
